# Delphi - TakePhotoFromCameraAction - photo resolution

Tags: delphi, camera, firemonkey

This is what my code looks like for saving photos in Firemonkey on Android.
The photos save, but in very poor quality. Despite the fact that the camera is set to max resolution, I get photos that are 462px x 1000px.
Does anyone know how to change this ?

```
procedure TMainForm.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
var
   path: string;
   jpgQuality : TBitmapCodecSaveParams;
begin
   //memo1.lines.Add(inttostr(image.Width) +  '  '   +  inttostr(image.Height) ) // I get 462 x1000
   jpgQuality.Quality:= 100;
   path := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedPicturesPath, 'test' + '.jpg' );

Image.SaveToFile(path, @jpgQuality);

end;
```

Comment: Your update should be posted as an answer instead. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It isn't acceptable here to edit a solution into the question itself. Instead, do as Remy suggested, and write an answer containing that solution in the space provided below for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Too bad it's not in the documentation.

`TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` has `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties.

Comment: This answer could be improved greatly if you also posted the corrected version  of your code using these newly-found properties.